# Парсинг XML структуры через регулярные выражения в java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно распарсить такую строку

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object><svg:svg width=\"208.0\" height=\"364.0\"><svg:polygon points=\"2.0 182.0 60.0 45.5 60.0 152.0 206.0 152.0 206.0 212.0 60.0 212.0 60.0 318.5\" fill=\"#ff0000\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"2.0\" transform=\"rotate(90.0,104.0,182.0)\"/></svg:svg></fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

и получить соответственно все параметры (width, height, points[] и т.д.), подозреваю, что лучше использовать регулярные выражения, однако сам с ними никогда не работал. Просьба, знающие люди, подскажите как лучше решить данную задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае регулярные выражения стоит применять, если Вы сами умеете их составлять. В противном случае лучше применять xml парсеры.
Возможно таких выражений Вам хватит:

```
Matcher m1=Pattern.compile("\\<svg:svg width=\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\" height=\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\""); // результат в 1 и 2 группе
Matcher m2=Pattern.compile("\\<svg:polygon points=\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\""); // результат в первой группе
```

Answer (score 3):

Для вашего случая, я бы честно воспользовался встроенным в язык XML-парсером. Это гарантирует отсутствие головной боли при, допустим, смене порядка параметров или наличии лишнего пробела тут и там.

Вот вам пример работы с ним: http://javist.ru/category/javax-xml-parsers/

По моему мнению, регулярные выражения удобны только если структура документа статична, при сложной структуре ваши регулярные выражения легко станут необозримыми и сложными в отладке и поддержке.